# boto3 list_services() with order

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I made aws auto deployment code with `boto3` library.

In my code, get all service list and use it.

I have to get lastest service. But I think there is no order option.

(https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.list_services)

Sometimes, first element is latest service.

But sometimes, old service is placed in first element.

Is there any option or way to get latest service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [list_services](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.list_services) method does not return details of individual services. It simply lists the services, and returns you a list of identifiers (ARNs) for those services.

To get more details of a given service, you can use [describe_services](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_services). This allows you to get details of up to 10 services at a time.

So, take the list of service identifiers that you get back from list_services, and pass it to describe_services (with at most 10 service identifiers). Something like this (untested):

```
list_response = client.list_services(
    cluster='xyz',
    launchType='EC2'
)

desc_response = client.describe_services(
    cluster='xyz',
    services=list_response['serviceArns']
)
```

Note that you will have to do pagination using `maxResults` / `nextToken` if there are a lot of results.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks :)